# Affine Model using Ransac

Tags: matlab, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, affinetransform

RANSAC is used to find Homography matrix relating two Images . In order to calculate the Matrix , we require atleast 4 correspondences . The Homogrpahy matrix is general 3*3 matrix describing any perspective transformation . If we are given only 3 correspondences , then How to calculate the the Homogrpahy Matrix ? It is given that the two images are affine related , hence we can calculate the Matrix using only 3 correspondences .

Comment: Your question is too broad and can be solved through reading textbooks or literatures papers!

Comment: @Constantine: Could you please suggest me some literature papers

Comment: "An Invitation to 3D computer vision" or "Multiple-view Geometry for computer vision" are good to start with!

Comment: In OpenCV, there is a `getAffineTransform` function ([documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#getaffinetransform)) which computes the first two rows of the 3x3 affine transform associated with 3 point correspondences. For RANSAC estimation with several unreliable correspondences, you would have to do the implementation yourself using this function.

Answer (score 2):

The first place to look for literature about the subject could be the book *Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision*, by Hartley and Zisserman.

From 3 correspondences you can find an affine homography *A* of size 3x3, that maps each 2D image point *p* to each point *q* with the following equation (assuming *p* and *q* are 2D points in homogeneous form):

```
A*p = q
```

To find *A* that matches three sets of point pairs: *{p1, p2, p3} -> { q1, q2, q3 }* you just have to stack the points in two matrices *P* and *Q*, both of size 3x3.

Matrix *'P'* is such that cells *P(1,i)* and *P(2,i)* should contain the first and second coordinate of the *i*-th point *p*. Matrix *Q* is such that cells *Q(1,i)* and *Q(2,i)* should contain the first and second coordinate of the *i*-th point *q*.

Cells *P(3,i)* and *Q(3,i)*, for *i=1..3* will contain 1 (for the homogeneous coordinates).

Once formed these matrices, you can find *A* by solving:

```
A*P = Q
```

I.e., by simply:

```
A = Q*P.inv()
```

Note however, that what you are looking for is a projective planar homography, and you require 4 points minimum to calculate it, and a different method. You must solve the equation:

```
H * p α q
```

where *H* is the homography you are looking for, and α means proportionality. To find *H* from four correspondences you must use the [Direct Linear Transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_linear_transformation) method. Nevertheless, in OpenCV you can use [findHomography](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?highlight=findhomography#findhomography) to find *H*.

Hope it helps, regards.

Answer (score 0):

unlike homography matrix "prespective tranformation", an affine transformation matrix is a 2X3 matrix with 6 degree of freedom. Thus requires only 3 points correspondence to compute.

You can simply convert this matrix into 3X3 homogeneous matrix by add a row at bottom with entries [0 0 1]. reason being that in affine matrix there is no prespective deformation (keystoning / chirping).

let me know if you need further explaination